# vocabulary: proper title for the head of a department

Tags: word-meaning, word-request

Is it correct to refer to the head of the personnel department in a company as its **president**?

If not, what should the position be called?

Comment: Depends. The naming system varies. It could be a **chief finance officer** -- head of the finance department. This is a broad question or primarily opinion-based, I think.

Answer (score 1):

No. The **head of the personnel department** is the **department head**.